# Android studio : InvalidVirtualFileAccessException: Accessing invalid virtual file:

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.2

> Just updated the SDK and got the following error, and my android version is

### InvalidVirtualFileAccessException: Worker exited due to exception: Accessing invalid virtual file: jar:///Users/Android/android-sdk/platforms/android-25/android.jar!/; original:239; found:159070

My Android studio version is Android studio 2.3 RC 1

Answer (score 33):

File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart

Everything is fine.

Answer (score 4):

As Maragues says https://github.com/square/sqldelight/issues/289

Try to clean and rebuild the project, otherwise restart the IDE

I hope this works for you

Comment: Clean is what generates the message, at least for ME.

Comment: try to rebuild it

Comment: I did. Same problem. And now I've invalidated the cache and restarted, losing all my history, but I knew that going in .

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Version Control

remove broken VCS mappings